# Redis Server failed, Socket failure, output buffer limits exceeded, how can I increase the limits?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I do basic pub/sub on a single machine, with my client being StackExchange-Redis's C# client and I run a Windows based Redis server on the same machine (Server version 2.8.4)

When I publish a larger amount of data (slightly larger than 32mb) I am getting the below error messages. I am not sure whether the error originates on the client side or whether it is raised by the server. Apparently the "output buffer limits" are exceeded. How can I increase the limits? I need to occasional send data of such payload (though that is the exception rather than the norm).

I am not sure this is related but each time I start my server a file is opened/generated that is roughly 32gb in size (???), filename "RedisQFork_3564.dat". What is this file used for? Is it all related to my issue?

**Error message on server**

`[10144] 23 May 17:37:29.293 # Client addr=127.0.0.1:47943 fd=9 name=DESKTOP-PC a
ge=20 idle=13 flags=N db=0 sub=7 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=88 oll=1
 omem=108527608 events=rw cmd=subscribe scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcomi
ng of output buffer limits.
[10144] 23 May 17:37:38.802 # Client addr=127.0.0.1:47948 fd=10 name=DESKTOP-PC
age=9 idle=9 flags=N db=0 sub=7 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=88 oll=1
omem=109314040 events=rw cmd=subscribe scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcomin
g of output buffer limits.`

**Error message on client**

`Message: Connection to Redis Server failed: SocketFailure on 127.0.0.1:6379/
Subscription, input-buffer: 4583028, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-wri
te: 8s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, last-heart
beat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s ago, global: 0s ago`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check here](http://redis.io/topics/clients) at the documentation from Redis. Look for header "Output buffers limits", I think this will put you in the right direction

As of 2.6.9 the following can be set using CONFIG SET

client-output-buffer-limit

Comment: I already saw it, but it does not show how to alter the limits. I think I reached pub/sub hard limit of 32mb but I like to know how to increase the buffer limit.

Comment: thanks, but would you know where to alter it in the config file? I did not see it. thanks

Comment: this only changes the instance it is called against. It is very useful for tweaking run-time settings, but you are responsible for persisting the configuration to disk yourself. See if you can run CONFIG GET * and see what gets returned

Comment: Thanks, both worked, through the config file and also setting the value through the client

Comment: Would you know what the file "RedisQFork_5464.dat" is supposed to do? It is 33gb in size and worries me a bit. Is that related to memory mapping?

Comment: @MattWolf these are snapshots of Redis heap. [See the details](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/issues/83).

Comment: @andreycha, thank you, will take a look as I have not monitored those snapshots in a while.

Answer (score 5):

The qfork file is how the MSOpenTech have emulated Linux forks for the Windows port, via a mempry-mapped file. You can control the size by setting the maxheap setting in the conf file.